# Сортировка на wordpress по нескольким параметрам

Tags: php, wordpress

помогите исправить ошибки, чтобы реализовать такую сортировку:

1. по таксономии(district)
2. произвольное поле (ASC)
3. другое произвольное поле(ASC)
4. произвольное поле 3го пункта, но DESC

с сортировкой по произвольным полям проблем нет, за исключением как  передать параметр (ASC или DESC)
и второй вопрос, как в этот код добавить сортировку по таксономии(сейчас представленный вариант не работает)

форма фильтров

```
<div class="area-input__hiden sorting-wrapper">
<label class="sort-name" for="sort-dist">
    <input class="sort-radio" id="sort-dist" name="sorting" value="category" type="radio">
    <span class="sort-text">По микрорайонам</span><!--ASC-->
</label>
<label class="sort-name" for="sort-area">
    <input class="sort-radio" id="sort-area" name="sorting" value="area" type="radio">
    <span class="sort-text">По площади</span><!--ASC-->
</label>
<label class="sort-name" for="sort-cost-u">
    <input class="sort-radio" id="sort-cost-u" name="sorting" value="price" type="radio">
    <span class="sort-text">По возрастанию цены</span><!--ASC-->
</label>
<label class="sort-name" for="sort-cost-d">
    <input class="sort-radio" id="sort-cost-d" name="sorting" value="price-2" type="radio">
    <span class="sort-text">По убыванию цены</span><!--DESC-->
</label>
</div>
```

код сортировки

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'category' => array(
            'taxonomy' => 'district',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'order' => 'ASC'// таким способом понятно не работает
        ),
        'area' => array(
            'key' => 'houses-area',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'order' => 'ASC'// таким способом понятно не работает
        ),
        'price' => array(
            'key' => 'cost-per-metr',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'order' => 'ASC'// таким способом понятно не работает
        ),
        'price-2' => array(
            'key' => 'cost-per-metr',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'order' => 'DESC'// таким способом понятно не работает
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => $_POST['sorting']
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

код сортировки не верен, вы не можете искать по таксономии в параметре meta_query, для этого есть параметр tax_query. так же на сколько я помню wp не дает возможности сортировать записи по таксономиям. вот так вы можете выбрать все записи у которых есть таксономия district и отсортировать их по значения мета полей

```
$args = [
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'district',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS',
        ]
    ],
    'meta_query' => [
        'area' => [
            'key' => 'houses-area',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ],
        'price' => [
            'key' => 'cost-per-metr',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ],
        'price-2' => [
            'key' => 'cost-per-metr',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ],
    ],
];

if ( ! empty( $_POST['sorting'] ) ) {
    $args['orderby'] = [
         $_POST['sorting'] => $_POST['sorting'] == 'price-2' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC',
    ];
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но не могу понять последнюю круглую скобку

Comment: Опечатка) исправил

Comment: странно, вообще сортировка не работает теперь

Comment: вы уверенны что сортировка не работает? попробуйте заменить порядок в сортировке например asc на desc

Comment: наверное я не правильно понял, ведь у вас радио кнопка для сортировки а значит вы можете сортировать только по одному параметру за запрос...

Comment: @DmitriyMedvedkin я обновил код в ответе, теперь сортировка должна работать, только учтите что сортировка по таксономии не работает

Comment: Darth KYL спасибо огромное, всё заработало